# stop my git repository compressing Compressing objects: 98% (36269/36738)

Tags: git

i try made a clone of the repository and this stop at 99% of compression objets and i think maybe the solution can the compresion of the repository and ran :
git gc --aggressive and the command stop in 98%.the largest file of my repository have over 200 MB.   How i can repair the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your repository is corrupt, you can check what objects have a problem with

```
git fsck --full
```

Then you can act accordingly on the problem objects.

Comment: but the execution of this commant is very large? i´m running in my repo but it is taking many time. thanks for help me

Comment: later many time this return me : dangling commit eae1893c2bd17f2e4c4162ca9fa8788e921ab516

Comment: This one should not take too long as it is just checking whether the objects are corrupt and whether the DAG is still in good order.

Comment: The dangling commit is nothing to worry about. It will eventually get garbage collected.

Comment: then, how is the cause of my compresion proccess stopped at 98%. i don´t worry for dangling commit??

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of large files with

```
git filter-branch
```

You will need to specify the proper options on this command. Once you have taken the large file out of your repository, your clone should be fast.

Comment: with this command remove file to control version, but are the file in the repo? this archive is a .sql that i don´t want control version but i want download it in git clone......